# how to add paragraph in a table

Tags: tables, longtable, paragraphs

[image: table with paragraph]

```
\begin{table}[thb]\centering
    \caption{Summary of present reviews.}
    \label{tab:table2}
    %\resizebox{0.48\textwidth}{!}{
    \large
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \toprule
       Ref. & Key contribution\\
        \midrule
        \cite{prema2021critical} &  Several machine learning models have been reviewed by the author. Comparative analysis suggested that combination models, deep learning, and principle component analysis(PCA) based models, Random forest(RF) algorithm have performed better in terms of accuracy and stability. 
      The clustered PSO-SVM-ARMA model provided better results \\
        B &  4 \\
        Ours & 4 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    %}
\end{table}
```

I want top create a table like i have attached, and the code i have tried. I am not able to add the paragraph, only one line is coming in the table

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please note that the site guidelines suggest waiting for a few hours at least, and generally a day or more, before "accepting" any given answer? Why? Because by immediately "accepting" the very first answer that's provided, one basically discourages others from posting additonal, potentially even better answers.

Comment: many thanks @Mico will keep it in my mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that formats all three columns according to the screenshot you posted. The third column provides automatic hanging indentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
% format of third column
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}

% format of second column
\newlength\mylen % create a scratch length variable
\settowidth\mylen{September 2017}            % measure max. width of 2nd column
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\raggedright}b{\mylen}}  % allow automatic line breaking

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]%
             {justification=RaggedRight, 
              singlelinecheck=off,
              labelfont=bf,
              labelsep=quad,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip,
             }
             
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules  
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of present reviews.}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l B L @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Work} & \textbf{Date of publication} & \textbf{Main contribution} \\
\midrule 
\cite{some_source} & September 2016 & \lipsum[1][1-5] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Do you know if ragged2e will eventually be part of the core code (so that the package is not needed anymore)?

Comment: I ask because I see the package being used by experts very often. Going offline now.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Thanks. I'm afraid I have no idea what the future may hold for the `ragged2e` package. I agree that it's a very useful package -- I suppose that's the main reason for me using it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the second column you should use "paragraph" type of columns as are `p{<width>` or `X` column type. The latter is  defined in the `tabularax` package and it enable that column width determine LaTeX.

The simplest way is for table use of the `tabularx` package and for the second column `X` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Summary of present reviews.}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}% <<<- changed
    \toprule
Ref.    & Key contribution\\
    \midrule
\cite{prema2021critical}    
        &  Several machine learning models have been reviewed by the author. Comparative analysis suggested that combination models, deep learning, and principle component analysis (PCA) based models, Random forest(RF) algorithm have performed better in terms of accuracy and stability. The clustered PSO-SVM-ARMA model provided better results \\
B       &  4 \\
Ours    & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

My first version of answer is based on provided MWE. It also consider question as was written. However, now I see (recognize), that you like to have more than what you ask: reproduction of showed image,  i.e. a table with three columns and fancy paragraph style (which I not like, but I add it anyway).

For this changes I estimate that is (very) suitable to use `tabularray` package. Using it the code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}   % if you liked
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}   
\captionsetup[table]% for reproducing table caption style
             {singlelinecheck=off,
              labelfont=sc,
              labelsep=quad,
              skip=1ex
             }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Summary of present reviews.}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l Q[l, b] X[j, cmd={\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}]},
             row{1} ={font=\small\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Ref.    
    & {Date of\\ publication}
            &   Key contribution\\
    \midrule
\cite{prema2021critical}
        & September 2016
            &  Several machine learning models have been reviewed by the author. Comparative analysis suggested that combination models, deep learning, and principle component analysis(PCA) based models, Random forest (RF) algorithm have performed better in terms of accuracy and stability. The clustered PSO-SVM-ARMA model provided better results \\
B       &   & 4 \\
Ours    &   & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Poonam Dhaka, see addendum to answer :-)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, works great for me.